# Calling template function inside function C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have similar case but more complex. I am trying to call a template function inside a normal function but I can't compile...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void ioo(T& x) { std::cout << x << "\n"; }

template<class T, class ReadFunc>
void f(T&& param, ReadFunc func) {
    func(param);
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    std::string y = "something";
    f(x, &::ioo);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ioo` is a function template, not a function, so you can't take its address.

This would however work since it instantiates the function `void ioo<int>(int&)`:

```
f(x, &ioo<decltype(x)>);
```

and as noted by Jarod42 in the comments, you could make it into a lambda:

```
f(x, [](auto& arg){ioo(arg);});
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed - added that as an option. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks that second comment was helpful for me. I had multiple params but I use ```f(x, [](auto&&... arg){ioo(...arg);});```

Comment: @IonutAlexandru You are welcome! You may want to take a look at `std::forward` too in order to do perfect forwarding.